# How do I install Bravura for Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

Or any music font, for that matter. I have literally tried on and off for years to get this to work and I can't seem to get it. I'm using MacOS, if that is at all relevant.

Comment: Have you tried with that package: https://github.com/lyp-packages/bravura ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bravura in LilyPond with the BMusicFonts package. https://github.com/dbenjaminmiller/bmusicfonts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).